# How do I ask the right questions assuming basic knowledge?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Recently, [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773862/can-i-convert-a-non-const-function-argument-to-const-and-set-the-size-of-array/46773934?noredirect=1#46773934) I could not find on Stack Overflow.

An answer was provided to the question and, when I asked for clarification the user indicated:

> @Mushy: this is basic C++ knowledge. Have you read an introductory C++ book? Additionally, the cppreference pages for std::array and std::vector should help you.

I have read [Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I own and read

- The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition (Stroustrup)
- C++ Primer Fifth Edition (Lippman)

in addition to other books and internet resources like

[en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)

I was asking the user who posted the answer to explain how a template argument can be considered a `const` initializer for array size. Perhaps he misunderstood and thought I was asking "what is a template function".

Is it acceptable on Stack Overflow to ask for clarification? Should I refrain and try to figure it out myself?

Comment: When you post a comment like that 3 minutes after the user posted the answer then he's not likely to be convinced you did sufficient research yet.  And of course you didn't.  So consider doing it and perhaps you now have a new question you can ask.

Comment: I'd argue that this is somewhat rude.  If they felt like your question was poorly researched, then a downvote would've gone further than a snide remark.

Comment: @Makoto It's not a snide remark.  It's polite and helpful advice on what the person has done wrong, what to do instead, and how to avoid the problem in the future.  Additionally, you cannot downvote a comment, your only options here are to reply or not reply.

Comment: @Servy:  I disagree.  The comment reads, "This is basic stuff.  Have you read up on this?"  I'm not sure how this is meant to be interpreted as "polite".  Also, I am *acutely* aware that one cannot downvote comments.  My opinion was that if the commentator felt that this was truly that basic, they'd be more constructive by downvoting the question rather than introducing the comment (which has confused the OP of *this* question into thinking that they've done something terribly wrong by asking a question here).

Comment: @Servy:  The intent is one thing, but there *are* nicer ways to guide someone to basic documentation.

Comment: @Makoto How is it meant to be interpreted as "snide".  The comment *is* something that the user should be reading up on.  How else would you prefered them to convey that they should have researched the topic instead?  You've said that they should downvote, but of course they can't, because one cannot downvote a comment, so you have provided no alternative means of conveying to Mushy that they should be researching using a book/documentation to find that information.

Comment: @Servy:  I stand by my remarks.  The intention is plainly clear - this is normally something one would find by researching it.  Saying, "This is basic, why haven't you read up on this?" is *not* constructive.  I'd have personally suggested to the OP that this is information that one could find in a specific book,  and if I had that book which pointed to that specific reference, I'd give 'em a chapter title or a page number.  I'd make it seem less...snide...from an outside perspective.

Comment: @Makoto You mean like telling them exactly what page in the documentation contains the exact answer to their question...like they did in their comment?  Saying that you stand by your statement that they should have downvoted **when they are physically incapable of downvoting a comment** is nonsensical.  They *can't* do as you suggest and refuse to tell them what they've done wrong and only downvote, all that they can do is comment to tell them where to find the information, which is exactly what they did.

Comment: @Servy Makoto said, _"...they'd be more constructive by downvoting the **question**..."_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @AndrewMyers The question was posted as a comment, not as a question.  Downvoting some unrelated post because of a problematic comment makes no sense (it implies that there's a problem with the question, when there isn't, and doesn't indicate a problem with the comment, when there is one), it in no way conveys useful information to...anyone.

Comment: @HansPassant _And of course you didn't._ If you read my question, not only do I identify resources I have read but also books I am presently reading for C++11... no, I did sufficient research in my own opinion.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with it, you asked the poster about the answer.  Pretty strange disconnect.  The poster is not obligated to limit his solution to what you might have researched.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it acceptable on Stack Overflow to ask for clarification?

As long as you don't pester the answerer it most certainly is. Many things seem basic to an experienced programmer and if you didn't understand part of the answer you should explain which part and  ask to clarify or if it's too big and too different from the original question ask a new one.

Not exactly what you did though. What you perceive you did:

> I was asking the user who posted the answer to explain how a template argument can be considered a const initializer for array size.

What you actually did:

> Can you please explain how this works?

What was he supposed to understand from that? If you have a problem explain what the actual problem is. How this works? or How do I do that? are never good on SO. I assume he was somewhat annoyed by it and responded in a somewhat rude way. Later he still helped you so I don't think you have anything to complain about.

Answer (score -3):

"Is it acceptable on SO to ask for clarification? Should I refrain and try to figure it out myself?"

First, this is two questions. My answers are:

1. No, if a new question is called for, ask a new question. Or just don't "accept" the answer and explain why... "I would accept this answer, but it's unclear because..."

And yes, it is acceptable, provided you're not going off on a tangent. And maybe try to add that clarity yourself. I wouldn't stress over it too much, most people here are very nice.

2. Should you refrain? It's up to you. But I think unique, basic questions are perfectly valid. Because we will always have lots of beginners coming here. Ask yourself: Would other beginners find this useful? If there really is "prerequisite" knowledge, I bet that's already explained here somewhere. (Or it should be added to the appropriate "ask a question" page.)

Also your two questions here are different from your title. I recommend asking only one question at a time, and keeping the title in sync with the actual question. The "real" question can change as you think through a question/problem, but remember to update the title to match what you're really thinking/writing. Update: Don't get me wrong, people should *try* to get their title correct before posting the question, not after posting.

Comment: It's not unacceptable to ask a follow up question.  This particular follow up question wasn't a good one, but they're not universally unacceptable.  It is also important to do one's research before asking questions.  As the help center says right at the start of the guidelines of how to ask a question, it's appropriate to do one's research.  It is *not* okay to edit a question into a different question just because you've realized that you actually want to know something different.

Comment: To answer the title. I wouldn't force it for the sake of accumulating points. You will naturally run into real problems, and those problems that have difficult solutions, they make good questions. As a beginner, you should assume the most basic questions have already been asked, and put in some real effort before asking something that's already asked. That said, standards change over time, or some documentation was really bad and disguised some forgotten feature, or some API changed, so all of this is evolving.

Comment: @Servy I agree with that 100%

Comment: If you agree, then you should edit the answer to not say the exact opposite of all of the points that I laid out, because in your answer you say that follow up questions are unacceptable, it's up to them if they want to actually do their research, and that they should edit their question into a different question as their problem changes over time, none of which are correct.

Comment: @servy Already done. And notice I qualified it as "my answer" rather than an absolute rule.

Comment: @servy However, I disagree about changing titles. I edit incorrect titles all the time, or add the necessary clarity to misleading titles. That is very helpful for people to do. Clicking a link and finding out the person is asking something else is a real pain. Obviously people should *try* to get their title correct before posting the question, not after posting.

Comment: I never said that the title should be out of sync with the question.  I have said that the line, "The 'real' question can change as you think through a question/problem" is not appropriate.  You cannot change your real question as you think through a problem.  The question you ask needs to stay the same.  If you have a new question, then you need to ask a new question, not edit an existing question into a new question.

Comment: @servy I've now clarified it... "before posting the question." These changes are called *editing* and everyone should try to proofread before, and after posting.